# Purpose of checking if $event exists in Angular change event

Tags: angular, angular-material2

From the example on Angular Material 2 Table, there is this a null check for `$event` before calling the handler. What is it checking for in this context? I can't seem to find any document indicating when `mat-checkbox` would emit `null` to the `(change)` event.

https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

```html
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
  <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
  </mat-checkbox>
</mat-header-cell>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why they have it either. Maybe you should log an issue with them about their documentation.

Looking through [their source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/checkbox/checkbox.ts), it will never emit a falsy value.

```js
private _emitChangeEvent() {
    let event = new MatCheckboxChange();
    event.source = this;
    event.checked = this.checked;

    this._controlValueAccessorChangeFn(this.checked);
    this.change.emit(event);
}
```

Additionally, in that same example they have another checkbox where they don't do that.

```xml
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
              [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
              [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
              (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking up the source! Marking this as correct answer because it's the most helpful